# Java, find intersection in integer list

Tags: java, algorithm

I have an object ArrayList like:

```
{{"ObjectName",[[1,3],[11,24]]},
{"ObjectName2",[[3,4],[5,6],[12,20]]},
{"ObjectName3",[[30,38]]}}
```

The object is formed by a string(object name) and many pairs of integer list inside a integer list.

A pair of integer list like [11,24]: means from 11cm to 24cm, a length range.

How could I use Java code and **less** bigO to check if the pairs of length of 1 object has an intersection with other objects' length range. Like ObjectName2 has a pair of integer [12,20] is intersect with ObjectName's [11,24].

I have a sudo code has bigO(n^3):

```
for(Object o1 : Arraylist){
   for(Object o2 : Arraylist){
       for(int x = 0; x < o1.lengthlist.size(),x++){

            if(o1.lengthlist.get(x)[0]>=o2.lengthlist.get(x)[0]
                && o1.lengthlist.get(x)[1]<=o2.lengthlist.get(x)[1])
               {got the intersection part}
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: Unless you write some code, there isn't a way to find intersection of values.

Comment: This is an example of the "object phobia" antipattern.  Instead of storing arrays, create a Range class to encapsulate each pair of ints, and give that class a method like `intersects` or `overlaps`.  Then, you'll probably want to use that method to write a static method that will do that check for multiple Range instances.

Comment: You will need to compare each element if its in the interval defined.

Comment: Might want to make sure that o1 != o2, and the second part of your if statement checks array position [1] both times.

Comment: Also, you describe your algorithm as BigO(n^3), but I don't think it really is. n is defined as... what? n should be the number of ranges you need to check, so correct me if I'm wrong, but this is BigO(n^2).

Comment: Don't I need to count the last inner loop? @SaviourSelf

Comment: Unless this is homework, it would make more sense to not reinvent the wheel. Use [Guava's `Range` utility](https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/RangesExplained) and declare your data as `Map<String, Iterable<Range<Integer>>> rangeMap`. Then, permute the map entries as you wish and check for intersections within the ranges using [`Range.isConnected()`](http://google.github.io/guava/releases/snapshot/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Range.html#isConnected%28com.google.common.collect.Range%29) (an intersection exists if and only if two ranges are connected.)

Comment: @milkmua BigO isn't measured by the number of nested loops. It can sometimes be used as a shortcut to determine worst case running time if you have n defined. In your situation, you're using "n^3", but you haven't defined n, and one of your for loops has a different bound. If you define n as the total number of ranges, then the answer is you must check every range against every other range, giving n^2.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I did a full example of how to do it.

Class 1

```
package intersectioninintegerlist;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

/**
 *
 * @author Ahmad
 */
public class IntersectionInIntegerList {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Pair> lst1 = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(new Pair(1,3), new Pair(11,24)));
        Obj obj1 = new Obj("obj1", lst1);

        List<Pair> lst2 = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(new Pair(3,4), new Pair(5,6), new Pair(12,20)));
        Obj obj2 = new Obj("obj2", lst2);

        List<Pair> lst3 = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(new Pair(30,38)));
        Obj obj3 = new Obj("obj3", lst3);

        List<Obj> objs = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(obj1, obj2, obj3));

        for(int i = 0; i < objs.size(); i++){
            for(int j = i+1; j < objs.size(); j++){
                findIntersect(objs.get(i), objs.get(j));
            }
        }

    }

    private static void findIntersect(Obj o1, Obj o2) {
        System.out.println(o1.name + " - " + o2.name);
        for(Pair p1 : o1.pairs){
            for(Pair p2 : o2.pairs){
                int A = p1.i1;
                int B = p1.i2;
                int X = p2.i1;
                int Y = p2.i2;
                if((A >= X && A <= Y) || (X >= A && X <= B)){
                    System.out.println(o1.name + " intersects with " + o2.name);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Class2

```
package intersectioninintegerlist;

import java.util.List;

/**
 *
 * @author Ahmad
 */
public class Obj {

        public String name;
        public List<Pair> pairs;

        public Obj(String n, List<Pair> p){
            name = n;
            pairs = p;
        }
}
```

Class3

```
package intersectioninintegerlist;

/**
 *
 * @author Ahmad
 */
public class Pair {
        int i1;
        int i2;
        public Pair(int _i1, int _i2){
            i1 = _i1;
            i2 = _i2;
        }
}
```

Hope It helps.

Comment: What the algorithm bigO is?

Comment: basically, you will need to loop the list twice in order to compare each object with the other
now since you have 2 objects that needs to be compared, you will have to test the intervals of Object A with Object B's.
so I guess that's the minimum complexity you can get.

Comment: @SleimanJneidi I didn't know it was a homework, I started coding it as soon as I read the topic, since I love algorithms

Comment: @AhmadHammoud it is good that you love algorithms, but you shouldn't waste your time

Comment: @milkmua the intersect function is n^2

Comment: This's not homework question, it's just a method I thought to help me solve my way doing a homework, It's an example for letting my question be understandable. @SleimanJneidi